# Create one HTML table from multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table

I’m trying to create an HTMl table from data from several tables with values and the length of values in different arrays are the same.
I will simplify the example here by limiting it to two tables.

I would like to get something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfRaN.png)

But with my code I have :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TR6iS.png)

Moreover I dont' know how to add the average line and fill this under the age and I tried just with name and age to do easy.
If someone can Help me :)

JS:

```
let names = ["X","Y"]
let ages = [22,10]

const newTable = document.createElement("table");
    newTable.innerHTML = "<thead><th>Name</th><th>Index</th></thead>";
    for (let name of names) {

      let newRow = document.createElement("tr");
      const tdName= document.createElement("td");
      tdName.textContent = name;
      newRow.appendChild(tdName);
      newTable.appendChild(newRow);
    }

    for (let age of ages ) {

      let newRow = document.createElement("tr");
      const tdAge= document.createElement("td");
      tdAge.textContent = String(age);
      newRow.appendChild(tdAge);
      newTable.appendChild(newRow);
    }

    const target = document.getElementById('target');
    target.appendChild(newTable);
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: You're creating a new row for each name and each age. I would loop over the length (make sure they are the same), add a row for each iteration, and then add a cell for each array.

Comment: Thank you, it works well I updated the post to try to push the problem a little further if you don’t mind?

Comment: I really think you should accept my answer if it worked for you, and create a new question for this part, rather than moving the goalposts of the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create a new row for each name and age; you want a row for each "set" of items,so loop over the length (checking that they match) and then create a cell for each corresponding array item.

```js
let names = ["X", "Y"]
let ages = [22, 10]

const newTable = document.createElement("table");
newTable.innerHTML = "<thead><th>Name</th><th>Index</th></thead>";

if (names.length == ages.length) {
  for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {

    let newRow = document.createElement("tr");
    //name
    const tdName = document.createElement("td");
    tdName.textContent = names[i];
    newRow.appendChild(tdName);
    //age
    const tdAge = document.createElement("td");
    tdAge.textContent = String(ages[i]);
    newRow.appendChild(tdAge);
    newTable.appendChild(newRow);
  }
}
const target = document.getElementById('target');
target.appendChild(newTable);
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```